# MacOS selection rectangle fade out transition is gone

Tags: macos

One of the details I loved the most in Mac OS (or OS X) has always been the subtle fade out animation of the "selection rectangle" that you can make on your desktop or in finder to select multiple files. I have a habit of doing useless selections on my desktop when I idle sometimes and last week I was horrified when I realised the fade out animation had disappeared. I can't remember when I last saw it.

[image: This is a GIF of the selection thing I'm talking about (sadly without the fade out animation)]

Was it removed in Mojave or earlier? Sierra?
**Is there any way to bring the animation back?**

Comment: It seems it was removed in Mojave

Comment: There's a setting in System Preferences under Accessibility to enable or disable animations (Reduce Motion, à la iOS). Maybe disable/re-enable it (and reboot your Mac) will bring it back. I'm not sure it was completely removed in Mojave, just not enabled by default. Mac users love their eye-candy... :-) EDIT: it's called Marquee, by the way...

Comment: Apple returned that animation in the macOS 12 Monterey.

Comment: Finally!   The fade is back indeed